# firestore, ERROR Error: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code

```
this.db.collection("users").doc(this.name_user).update({
        data
        })
        .then(function() {})
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error! " + error);
        });
```

after executing the code gives me the following error

```
core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined
at new FirestoreError (error.js:149)
at ParseContext.createError (user_data_converter.js:162)
at UserDataConverter.parseScalarValue (user_data_converter.js:439)
at UserDataConverter.parseData (user_data_converter.js:339)
at user_data_converter.js:362
at Object.forEach [as c] (obj.js:49)
at UserDataConverter.parseObject (user_data_converter.js:361)
at UserDataConverter.parseData (user_data_converter.js:331)
at UserDataConverter.parseArray (user_data_converter.js:347)
at UserDataConverter.parseData (user_data_converter.js:327)
```

Any idea why this error ?, or something is wrong with my code?

I receive a json and process the data with a FOR loop, this is the code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i].id_expediente === this.id_exp ){
      console.log("update status");

     datos.splice(i, 1, {id_exp: data[i].id_exp,
        demandado: data[i].name,
        direccion: data[i].address,
        status: "start"
      });
    }
}
```

after this (for) print in console data

```
[

{
  "id_exp": "8989",
  "name": "user_name",
  "address: "Mexico, Mexico",
  "status": "start"
}
,
{
"id_exp": "8990",
  "name": "user_name2",
  "address": "Mexico, Mexico",
  "status": ""
},
{
"id_exp": "8995",
  "name": "user_name3",
  "address": "Mexico, Mexico",
  "status": ""
}
]
```

Comment: What is `data`?  Where does it come from?

Comment: data is what I get from the loop (for),  I have added more descriptions above.